# Tensorflow For Online Learning

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, normalization

Suppose I have a streaming data and I use SGD to train the Fully connected neural network chunk by chunk in tensorflow.

Problem I faced:

1. How to normalize raw data chunk by chunk?
2. Is it possible to use batch_normalization for raw data and feed it to fully connected NN?

Answer (score 0):

Re (1) you can use `tf.metrics.mean_tensor` to compute streaming mean and standard deviations.

Re (2) yes, you can probably do that with `batch_norm`.

Comment: When I use batch_norm for input raw data, then do fully-connected layer, no matter how small my learning rate is, the cross entropy is increasing. Without that batch_norm layer, everything goes right.

And I don't quite know how to use tf.metrics.mean_tensor for normalization train data and test data?

Comment: Batch normalization isn't guaranteed to work in every problem. Maybe you need to tune its parameters. To normalize the data by removing the mean, you can compute mean_tensor and subtract it from the data; you can also compute the variance by computing mean_tensor of the square of your tensor.